# SwiftMailer - Subject not sent if setBcc

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am trying to send an email with a bcc.

The subject line is sent only if there's not bcc, as soon as I add bcc no subject is sent anymore.

Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
    $message = new Swift_Message();
    $message ->setSubject('Your Subject')
             ->setFrom( array( 'a@b.co.uk' => 'Name 1' ) )
             ->setTo( array( $_REQUEST['email'] => $_REQUEST['name'] ) )
             ->setBcc(['b@b.co.uk' => 'Name 2'])
             ->setBody( $mail_message_customers, 'text/html' )
             ->attach( $attachment );
    $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
    $mailer    = Swift_Mailer::newInstance( $transport );
    $mailer->send( $message );
```

(The attached file is a pdf - this part works properly, so I don't think I need to post the pdf code here (to keep this question simple and more readable))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the issue was with the email address i was trying to bbc to and not to the code posted above.

It is working as expected now.